# textarea keyup event for submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here in my code I am having a textarea, where after user typed anything and press enter then some code need to be executed, but if the user press shift+enter then a new line should come in the textarea only. Below is my code so far --

```
<textarea id="commentarea<?php echo $row[slno]; ?>" class="secondtextareay pull-left" rows="2" cols="50" placeholder="Post comments here..." onkeyup="enter_comment(<?php echo $row['slno']; ?>,<?php echo $CUID; ?>);"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function enter_comment(postid,userpostedid) {
       if (event.which == 13) {
           document.getElementById('commentarea'+postid).value='';
           //insert_comment(id); // Call any function here: Just pass your actual Parameters to enter_comment().
       }
       else
       {
           return;
       }
}
</script>
```

Now, when I am pressing enter, it's working fine, but if I press shift+enter, then also it is doing the same. I want to prevent this, kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
   // shift+enter pressed
 }
 else if(event.keyCode == 13){
          //enter key pressed
}else{
    //nothing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the shift key was pressed or not through `event.shiftKey` property. So your event handler could be modified to:

```
function enter_comment(postid,userpostedid) {
       if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
           document.getElementById('commentarea'+postid).value='';
           //insert_comment(id); // Call any function here: Just pass your actual Parameters to enter_comment().
       }
       else if (event.which == 13 && event.shiftKey)
       {
            // Create the new line.
       }
       else
       {
           return;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `onkeydown`

> onkeydown is fired when the key is down

instead of `onkeyup`

> onkeyup is fired when the key is released

You can check shiftkey is pressed by `event.shiftKey(true/false)`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function enter_comment(postid,userpostedid) {
       if (event.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
           document.getElementById('commentarea'+postid).value='';
           event.preventDefault();
           //insert_comment(id); // Call any function here: Just pass your actual Parameters to enter_comment().
       }
}
</script>
```